# trying to uncheck radio buttons on quiz app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a friends quiz. This is my first ever JS project.

One of the things I am struggling to find a solution to is how to go about unchecking the radio button after the user has clicked 'submit answer'. At the moment I am using a for loop to try and set the condition back to false for the checked radio button, but it doesnt work.

Is someone able to look at this code and assist or point out what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var azeem = [
{
question: "What is Azeem's favourte color?",
choices: ["Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Green"],
answer: 0
},
{
question: "What is Azeem's favourte movie?",
choices: ["Scarface", "The Terminator", "Shawshank Redemption", "The Dark Knight"],
answer: 3
},
{
question: "What was Azeem's first ever job role?",
choices: ["Cleaner", "Store Assistant", "Sales", "Admin"],
answer: 1
},
{
question: "What is Azeem's favourite dish?",
choices: ["Pasta", "Pizza", "Chips", "Curry"],
answer: 0
},
{
question: "What subject did Azeem enjoy the most in school?",
choices: ["Drama", "Science", "P.E", "History"],
answer: 0
},
{
question: "What subject did Azeem least enjoy in school?",
choices: ["Geography", "Maths", "History", "I.T"],
answer: 1
},
{
question: "Which one of these cities has Azeem travelled to?",
choices: ["Madrid", "Lisbon", "Istanbul", "Dublin"],
answer: 1
},
{
question: "Which college did Azeem study in?",
choices: ["NewVic", "Redbridge", "East Ham", "Barking"],
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Who is Azeem's favourite sports icon?",
choices: ["Eric Cantona", "Muhammad Ali", "Cristiano Ronaldo", "Prince Naseem"],
answer: 1
},
{
question: "Who is Azeem's favourite music artist?",
choices: ["Michael Jackson", "Eminem", "Drake", "Linkin Park"],
answer: 1
},

];

var correctAnswers = 0;
var currentQuestion = 0;
var questionNumberCounter = 1;
var questionNumber = document.getElementById("questionCount");
var choices = document.getElementById("choicesSection");
var questions = document.getElementById("ques");
var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("answer");
questions.innerText = azeem[currentQuestion].question;


// The following event listener will transition from the instructions to the first question of the quiz

            document.getElementById("startquiz").addEventListener("click",function(){
$(".quiz-intro").fadeOut(600);
$(".quiz-section").delay(600).slideDown("slow");
questionNumber.innerText = questionNumberCounter;
azeem[currentQuestion].choices.forEach(function(value, index){
var radio = document.createElement("input");
var label = document.createElement("label");
var div = document.createElement("div");
$(div).addClass("choice");
radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
radio.setAttribute("name", "answer");
radio.setAttribute("value", index);
label.innerHTML = value +"<br>";
choices.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(radio);
div.appendChild(label);

})

})


            document.getElementById("submitanswer").addEventListener("click",function(){

if (!$('input[name=answer]:checked').length > 0){
alert("Please select an aswer");
return; 
} 

var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
questionNumberCounter++;
questionNumber.innerText = questionNumberCounter;
currentQuestion++
questions.innerText = azeem[currentQuestion].question;
azeem[currentQuestion].choices.forEach(function(value, ind) {
labels[ind].innerText = value;
});

var radioValue = $("input[name='answer']:checked").val();
if (radioValue === azeem[currentQuestion].answer){
correctAnswers++;
}

for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++){
if (radioButtons[i].checked === true){
radioButtons[i].checked === false;
}
}

})

        })
```

Comment: You need to fix your errors first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:
radioButtons[i].checked === false;

Should be:
radioButtons[i].checked = false;

Cheers.

Comment: Glad to help jimmy118